# Flutter how to remove extra spacing from GridView.builder element?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `GridView.builder` that build me a grid with elements inside, how can I remove the distance from the bottom of my grid element so that there is no overflow on all devices, I use the `screenutil` package.
[image]

Here is my griddelegate code:

```
Widget buildProduct(List<Product> product) => GridView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 20.w / 33.h,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10.w,
            mainAxisSpacing: 10.h,
        ),
        itemCount: product.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {...}
);
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying a fixed height for buildProduct's parent component?

Answer (score 0):

need more code to solve the problem but maybe you can try to wrap the `Gridview` with `Expanded` and remove `shrinkWrap`